# Updating parent key should change child key (foreign key)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables (parent, child).

the tables contain data as follows

```
test (child) 

type      version
--------  -------
bmw       M3
audi      RS6
mercedes  S500
audi      RS4
bmw       M3
audi      RS6

test2 (parent)

type     version (type & version are a combined unique key)
-------- -------
audi     RS4
audi     RS6
mercedes S500
bmw      M3

foreign key

ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test
FOREIGN KEY (version) REFERENCES test2(version);
```

I'm able to add data to the "child" table which creates a uniqe entry in the "parent" table using a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER on the "child" table. (INSERT INTO parent ... ON DUPLICATE KEY...)

What I want to be able to do is by updating the parent table (only version column), all the corresponding entries in the child table should be updated as well.

E.g. by changing RS6 to RS5 in the "parent" table I want to see the following change in the child table.

```
type      version
--------  -------
bmw       M3
audi      RS5
mercedes  S500
audi      RS4
bmw       M3
audi      RS5
```

But I get this error if I update a "version" field in the parent table.

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table`.`test`, CONSTRAINT `fk_test` FOREIGN KEY (`version`) REFERENCES `test2` (`version`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I even added an BEFORE UPDATE trigger to the child table (same as before insert)

I guess I'm doing it all wrong, but is there a way to do this with foreign keys or similar solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write a trigger to do what you describe.

You can do this with a foreign key by setting its action to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` which means a change in the parent will be duplicated in the child.

```
alter table test add foreign key (type, version) 
  references test2(type, version) 
  on update cascade;
```

This update happens simultaneously with the update to the parent.

For more information read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions

Comment: I did try the on cascade before you posted, seemed not to work at first. Then I set it up all again and it's working nicely now. Thanks to your comment which made me come back to that. However, shooting the sql you posted deleted my table somehow (not that I would care too much) but it seems to be lost in the database. Because if I try and create a table again using the same name I do get foreign key warning although there are no keys present. Do you maybe know how to clean that up?

Comment: It sounds like you created your parent table but you forgot the primary key.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should be changing a primary key like this, you should add an artificial key to the parent, and use to make the relationship with the children with a foreign key, then you can change the parent all you want and to get the value you join it in the query.